# Android get time of a call from CallLog

Tags: android

I have this code to get all the calls from CallLog class from Android

```
    private static ArrayList<CallStats> getCallDetails(Context context) {
    ArrayList<CallStats> arr = new ArrayList<CallStats>();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int name = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        CallStats call = new CallStats();
        call.callName = cursor.getString(name);
        call.callNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        call.callType = cursor.getInt(type);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(date)));
        call.callDate = callDayTime.toString();
        call.callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
        arr.add(call);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return arr;
}
```

and I use this array list to make a list view with all the calls. What I want is, to make the date somehow to show in minutes or hours if the call is from today, like in the original phone app.
For example, if someone was called 5 mins ago, to show (5 mins ago)
or if it was few days ago to show (2 days ago)
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29) to achieve this.

For example

```
Date now = new Date(); 
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(callDayTime.getTime(), now.getTime(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control over the result, you should write something yourself. The method should look something like this:

```
private static final int SECOND_MS = 1000;
private static final int MINUTE_MS = SECOND_MS * 60; 
private static final int HOUR_MS   = MINUTE_MS * 60;

/**
 * Calculate human readable difference between endTime and startTime
 * @param: startTime in ms
 * @param: endTime in ms
 */
public String getElapsedTime(long startTime, long endTime){

    long diffMs = endTime - startTime;
    if(diffMs < MINUTE_MS){
        int seconds = diffMs / SECOND_MS;
        return seconds + " seconds ago";
    } else if(diffMs < HOUR_MS){
        int minutes = diffMs / MINUTE_MS;
        return minutes + " minutes ago";
    } ... etc
}
```

Note that you want to use string resources instead of hardcoded strings.